# How to get all UITextField values in UITableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm working with Core Data. I have a Core Data entity named **Users**. I'm listing **Users** in a UITableView. Multi-selection is enabled for UITableView. UITableViewCell subclass includes a UILable for **username** and UITextField for **price**. Also, I have a Core Data entity named **Expenses**.

The thing I'm trying to do is: I will enter prices for users, and will save to **Expenses** with the info of the user and price. For example:

1. I have 10 users listed in UITableView. (**DONE**)
2. All cells have UITextField for price. (**DONE**)
3. I enter prices in UITextField for 5 users which I selected. (**DONE**)
4. Get the info which includes userUID and price from selected cells. (**FAIL**)
5. Save **userUID** and **price** to **Expenses** with **doneButton**.

Here's what my Core Data entities look like:

Users:

```
@NSManaged public var userName: String
@NSManaged public var userUID: String
```

Expenses:

```
@NSManaged public var userUID: String
@NSManaged public var price: Int
```

```
class viewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

 var fetchedResultsController : 
    NSFetchedResultsController<Users>!


  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true 
  }


  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        fetchUsers() 

  }

  func fetchUsers() {
     ...... // FETCHING USERS FROM COREDATA
     tableView.reloadData()
  }

  @IBAction func doneButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
     // ????????????
  }


 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        guard let fetchRes  =  fetchedResultsController , let sections 
    = fetchRes.sections else {
            return 0
        }
        return sections.count
    }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
 section: Int) -> Int {

        guard let fetchRes  =  fetchedResultsController , let 
 sectionInfo = fetchRes.sections?[section] else {
            return 0
        }
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
 IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
          "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        let User = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)

        cell.lblUserName.text = User.userName

    return cell
 }

}
```

```
class CustomCell : UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var lblUserName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtPrice: UITextField!


}
```

The thing I want to do is, get `userUID` and price from UITextField from selected cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is you shouldn't use UITableViewCell as data storage because TableView can release them from memory if they are not present on the screen.

One option has data storage in ViewController and set a reference to it to cells. UITextField in this cell than set value directly into this data storage.

So with a done button, you can just read values from data storage.

Answer (score 0):

From my point, you need something like one more layer for the cell data

```
class CellViewModel {
    let user: User
    var price: Int/Double/String
}
```

After you fetch your Users you create the list of CellViewModel and keep it. And your `CustomCell` works with it (sets name and etc).

The cell should be a `UITextFieldDelefate` and change `price` in `CellViewModel`.

After you did all your changes you take a list of selected cells from `indexPathsForSelectedRows`. Now you have indexes of selected cells and list of your `CellViewModel`. Now you iterate through them and create your `Expenses`

Check `map` and `filter` methods for the list to make your solution more readable.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for answer. I solved the problem with textFieldDidEndEditing with using protocol.